# Possible to concat LISTAGG columns?

Tags: oracle, concatenation, listagg

Is it possible to preform LISTAGG on two different columns and concat them as well in oracle??

Example:

```
Select a, LISTAGG(b, ' , ') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY a) || ' ' || LISTAGG(c, ' , ') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY a)
FROM table 
GROUP BY a
```

Comment: What happened when you tried?

Comment: Error in list of function arguments: 'GROUP' not recognized.
Error in list of function arguments: ')' not recognized.
Error in list of function arguments: '|' not recognized.
Error in list of function arguments: ',' not recognized.

Comment: Did you run this directly in an Oracle database? Those errors don't look like ORA errors. Rather, it seems you initiated the query from some calling code. If so, you need to post that code; the error is not in the SQL statement.

Comment: Also, the "order by a" in the LISTAGG, while syntactically correct, is logically meaningless - since you are grouping by a, the ordering value (a itself) is constant within each group.

Comment: It's a little complicated, using a dataset in MVS that is connected to a ORACLE db for a WinForms application. I'm getting this error when building a query for a tableAdapter that is connected to a table in the ORACLE db. The query runs, the wizard just gives me those errors.

Comment: I don't think you can leave it empty, but if you really don't care about the order you can say ORDER BY NULL.

Comment: Ah, thank you. I attempted to leave it empty and kept getting a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot `concat` multiple `listagg` into a single column; instead, get all `listagg` values and *then* `concat`.

For example:

```
select
  a,
  b || '  ' || c as d
from (
  Select
    a,
    LISTAGG(b, ', ') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY a) b,
    LISTAGG(c, ', ') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY a) c
  FROM abc 
  GROUP BY a
);
```